# Is there an alternative for System.out.println without having to use System?

Tags: java, eclipse, system.out

I am currently having to create a class called 'System'
and I can't put System.out.println because the System is always referring to the class.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: Use the fully qualified name. `java.lang.System.out.println`. Better yet, don't call your class `System` when there is already a class called that which is implicitly part of every namespace by default.

Answer (score 4):

You can either:

- use the fully qualified name `java.lang.System`

  ```
  java.lang.System.out.println("Hello World!");
  ```

  or;
- statically import `java.lang.System.out` and use `out.println`:

  ```
  // at the top of the file
  import static java.lang.System.out;
  ...
  out.println("Hello World!");
  ```

  or;
- Rename your class to something else, not `System`. Surely you can find a better, more specific name than that. For example, if you are making a game, call it `GameSystem`. Whatever you are making, try appending it to `System` to make `XXXSystem`.

Comment: A caveat to the 2nd option: If you need to use some other object or a method from `System`, it's not the option you should go with.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's how you can create your own version of `System.out` without using the System class at all:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true);
```

You should explore the options given in other answers first (like use the fully qualified class name `java.lang.System` or rename your System class)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Maven, add to your pom.xml the following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Now you can add the `@Slf4j` annotation to your class and use `log.info("My message")`

There are several levels of logging. Read more about the annotation [here](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/slf4j/Slf4j.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to name your class like that, as already in java we have a class named System.
Alternatively, you can add a static import or use the fully qualified name of the Java class.

**Static Import**
*import static java.lang.System.*;*

But static imports can have ambiguity too, so I would suggest you to rename your class from System to something else, a bit related to your project.